# jQuery select list item in slider

Tags: jquery

Hee!

I'm building a simple slider, now its working perfectly only now I still have to give class names like slider1,slider2 enz

also this part seems silly  if (sliderNumber == 7) {

I'm wondering how I can improve my code to make it more responsive

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
      fadeSlider();
  });

  function fadeSlider() {
      sliderNumber = 1;
      $('.slide' + sliderNumber).addClass('active');
      fader();

      function fader() {
          if (sliderNumber == 7) {
              setTimeout(function () {
                  $('.slide' + sliderNumber).removeClass('active');
                  sliderNumber = 1;
                  $('.slide' + sliderNumber).addClass('active');
                  fader();
              }, 1000);
          } else {
              setTimeout(function () {
                  $('.slide' + sliderNumber).removeClass('active');
                  sliderNumber++;
                  $('.slide' + sliderNumber).addClass('active');
                  fader();
              }, 1000);
          }
      }
  }
```

Html

```
<ul class="totalSlider">
              <li class="totalRaised slide1">a</li>
              <li class="totalRaised slide2">b</li>
              <li class="totalRaised slide3">c</li>
              <li class="totalRaised slide4">d</li>
              <li class="totalRaised slide5">e</li>
              <li class="totalRaised slide6">f</li>
              <li class="totalRaised slide7">g</li>
</ul>
```

css

```
.totalSlider li{
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
}
.totalSlider li.active{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

and the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x7xk3295/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use following logic, toggling the active class:

```
$(fadeSlider);

function fadeSlider() {
    setInterval(function () { // use an interval if you want code to be called in loop
        var $next = $('.active').next().length ? $('.active').next() : $('.totalRaised:first-child'); //'next' element would be: if there is an element following current active one, the next one, otherwise, the first child
        $('.active').add($next).toggleClass('active');// toggle active class for the active one and the next one
    }, 1000);
}
```

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: Thank you, can you try explaining what you're doing here?

Comment: @IvoJonkers Which specific part don't you understand?

Comment: @A.Wolff  he is learning.. explain your code please :-) (edit: wrong tag)

Comment: var $next = $('.active').next().length ? $('.active').next() : $('.totalRaised:first-child'); 

I know you're getting the next one and adding it to a var, but I have no clue how it is working precisely

Comment: Cool thanks for the explanation!  this makes it a lot more clear